# Balancing data in Python by using SMOTE library

Tags: python

I want to balance a set of training data which has the following characteristics and its separated in X_train and y_train. The percentages of my classes are roughly the following:

```
class A: 54%
class B: 45%
class C: 1%
```

so I want to resample my data as the following:

```
class A: 49%
class B: 41%
class C: 10%
```

The library that I want to use is:

https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html

and using Smote as the balancing algorithm. The problem that I have is that I do not know how to do that with this library. I know the Smote algorithm, but I am having some difficulties with this library. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used sklearn before ? It's very similar to how that works. Effectively using smote is itself like running a model over your data to generate more dummy data to balance it.

This example from the [imblearn page](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) describes it well:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
>>> from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
>>> X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,
... weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0,
... n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)
>>> print('Original dataset shape %s' % Counter(y))
Original dataset shape Counter({1: 900, 0: 100})
>>> sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
>>> X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, y)
>>> print('Resampled dataset shape %s' % Counter(y_res))
Resampled dataset shape Counter({0: 900, 1: 900})
```

Specifically when you have your training data X and target y you instantiate an instance of SMOTE() with a random state if you wish. You then fit that onto your data `X_res,y_res = sm.fit_resample(X,y)`. The `fit_resample()` does two jobs in one it fits the SMOTE algorithm to your dataset and then transforms(resamples) your dataset with a new oversampled dataset.

Comment: Would it be possible to employ sm.fit_resample for only one data frame without dividing our data into X and Y?